# Using Google Sheet's v4 JSON Endpoint with my API but still getting "Unauthorized" message

Tags: javascript, json, google-api, endpoint

I am trying to get a simple JSON package from putting the URL of my Google spreadsheet so I can use it on my webpage; I am using my Google Cloud Console API as it is said on the documentation of the v4 Google API format, but I still get the error of "Unauthorized API"

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration#v4-api

I am using this URL:
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEET_ID/values/Sheet1?key=API_KEY

My google sheet is set as published on the web. And also I am the creator of the google sheet.

What could I be missing? I am new to API's!

[image: Message]

First Edit:
Answering the comment of ABDULLOKH MUKHAMMADJONOV
Here is the code I am using to make a GET request to the google sheet, you can see the Sheet ID is there, and also the API of the google cloud platform.

```
fetch("https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1S652uS2FLVoZ1m3apb6R4H783v6GkV58HbQ6Idec5aY/values/Sheet1?key=AIzaSyCpFZ7mcqMNc6Q_bP6h1kCEfAi6c_fd8AM", {"method": "get"})
.then( (httpResponse) => {
    if (httpResponse.ok) {
    console.log(httpResponse.json());
    return httpResponse.json();
    } else {
    return Promise.reject("Fetch did not succeed");
    }
} )
.then(json => console.log(json.someKey))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This code is from the Wix code editor.

Comment: Post the part of your code where you connect to the server(send a request).

Comment: If you are new to apis why are you following a migration guide are you trying to migrate from v3 to v4?

Comment: @DaImTo It is just the info I managed to get into when I was searching for it

Answer (score 0):

> The caller doesnt not have permissions

Means that the user you are authenticated as does not have permission to do what it is you are trying to do.

The method

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/SHEET_ID/values/Sheet1?key=API_KEY
```

I believe is this method [spreadsheets.values/get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get) if you check the documentation you will notice that it requires authorization with one of these scopes

[image]

You appear to only be sending an api key. You need to be authorized to access that sheet.  You cant access it with an API key that only grants access to public data.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will investigate how to use those OAuth scopes you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I investigated about the OAuth 2.0 authentication and authorization for using Google Sheet's REST API. I added one of the needed scopes.

But I am stuck at the point on how to do the authorization process...

I am looking at this google documentation - [How to use Google OAuth 2.0 authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2%20-%20https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/authorizing)

But I haven't been able to get to the answer I seek. I am stuck at the part where it says "When your application needs access to user data, it asks Google for a particular scope of access." I do now know how to code this request or to do this request through the Insomnia software.

I am trying to do the GET request with a wix testing website, and also with Insomnia, but I haven't been able to achieve it.

These are the images from Insomnia, which tell me "Invalid authorization URL"

[Insomnia's OAuth 2.0 authentication parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMBjw.png)

[Insomnia's API Query parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUJi1.png)